# Finding TimeZone ID with Timezone like "Europe/Germany"

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

I have an app with some date time zone formats mentioned in the DB which are like "Europe/Rome" , "Europe/Berlin", Is there a way to find out TimezoneId's using this timezone formats?

Comment: Short answer: No, not using any built-in .NET APIs.

Comment: See the linked duplicate for how to do this.  Jon's answer is also good.  But I assume by `Europe/Germany` in your title you actually meant `Europe/Berlin`, as the former is not a valid IANA time zone ID.

Answer (score 5):

When running on Windows, `TimeZoneInfo` uses the Windows time zone database, rather than the [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) which uses IDs of the form "Europe/Rome" etc.

While you *could* look for Windows time zone IDs containing the city name (as suggested in other answers), there's absolutely no guarantee that you'll always find such an ID, and I would recommend against doing so. Even if you find the right `TimeZoneInfo`, it won't necessarily have the same rules as the IANA database.

Instead, I'd recommend use a third-party library that supports the IANA time zone database. I maintain one such library, [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org), which is a whole alternative date/time API for .NET - but with conversions to and from `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` if you really need them. Other libraries also exist that use the IANA time zone database, but I believe Noda Time is the most widely adopted one.

If you really need to use `TimeZoneInfo`, you *could* use Noda Time to find the Windows IDs that match it most closely using [`TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.WindowsMapping`](https://nodatime.org/2.4.x/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.html#NodaTime_TimeZones_TzdbDateTimeZoneSource_WindowsMapping) in the 2.x version, or if you're using 3.x (currently in beta) there's [`TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.TzdbToWindowsIds`](https://nodatime.org/unstable/api/NodaTime.TimeZones.TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.html#NodaTime_TimeZones_TzdbDateTimeZoneSource_TzdbToWindowsIds) to make life simpler.